# A way to use count/contains on map holding iterator by giving const_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, const-iterator

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using Iterator = std::vector<int>::iterator;
using ConstIterator = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;

std::set<ConstIterator> s;

int main() { 
    bool equal = Iterator{} == ConstIterator{};
    s.count(Iterator{});
    s.count(ConstIterator{});
    s.contains(Iterator{});
    s.contains(ConstIterator{});
}
```

This code is [correct](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cVGjhJEYPaUUZsdw) since `ConstIterator` can be created from `Iterator`, but not vise versa. If we change `s` type to `std::set<Iterator>` function calls that use `ConstIterator` will fail the build.

As you know, both functions `count` and `contains` don't modify the collection, and internally they just do compare passed value with stored one. And that comparison is absolutely correct (see `equal` part from code example), we can compare for equality `Iterator` and `ConstIterator`. One possible workaround is to use `find_if` with lambda instead, e.g.:

```
std::ranges::find_if(s, [](auto v) { return v == ConstIterator{}; });
```

Hence, the question: how can we deal with `count`/`contains` in standard and beautiful way when we have `ConstIterator` and want to look into container where `Iterator`s are stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::set<Iterator, std::less<>>`, or `std::set<Iterator, std::ranges::less>` if you can use that.

These comparator types include an `is_transparent` member, which signals to `std::set` that it should support comparisons with any key-comparable type instead of converting to the key type. (The reason for the need to opt in is backward compatibility).

These types themselves also accept differing types in their comparison operator, as opposed to something like `std::less<int>` (the default for `std::set<int>`), which would specifically have `operator<(const int&, const int&)`.